# remove current fragment, and replace with a new one

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I tried to remove current fragment and replace with the first fragment `PemegangPolis`, everytime I click new button on my application, but I got nothing, this is my code :

```
case R.id.btn_new:
         android.app.FragmentTransaction fragTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         if (pemegangPolis.isAdded()) {
             fragTrans.remove(pemegangPolis);
             fragTrans.replace(R.id.frame_container, new PemegangPolis());
         }else if (tertanggungPolis.isAdded()) {
             getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(tertanggungPolis);
             fragTrans.replace(R.id.frame_container, new PemegangPolis());
         }else if (usulanAsuransi.isAdded()) {
             getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(usulanAsuransi).commit();
             fragTrans.replace(R.id.frame_container, new PemegangPolis());
         }else if (detailInvestasi.isAdded()) {
             getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(detailInvestasi).commit();
             fragTrans.replace(R.id.frame_container, new PemegangPolis());
         }else if (detail_Agen.isAdded()) {
             getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(detail_Agen).commit();
             fragTrans.replace(R.id.frame_container, new PemegangPolis());
         }else {
             if (dokumenPendukung.isAdded()) {
             getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(dokumenPendukung).commit();
             fragTrans.replace(R.id.frame_container, new PemegangPolis());
         }
         }
         fragTrans.commit();
         mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(SlidingMenu);
        break;
```

is there any wrong with my code? or am I missing something?

Comment: You have lots of if/else. Can you confirm when you debug that the code is reaching inside those blocks?

Comment: nothing means? is your listener code getting called?

Comment: i have a lots if/else because i think with this code, it should work, but it seems doesn't. its not refresh my fragment and not remove the curent fragment

Answer (score 3):

This code works for me :

```
Fragment fragment = new TypeOfFrag();
```

`android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();`

This code works for me. Try to adapt your code with this :-).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you are calling commit already on a transaction. This way the second (`replace`) is most probably not going to work.

Also, to perform a transaction, you don't have to remove the fragment at first. Just `replace` should be sufficient.

Depending on your app setup, you might need to replace `getFragmentManager()` with `getSupportFragmentManager`

```
case R.id.btn_new:
     android.app.FragmentTransaction fragTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     if (pemegangPolis.isAdded()) {

         fragTrans.replace(R.id.frame_container, new PemegangPolis());
     }else if (tertanggungPolis.isAdded()) {

         fragTrans.replace(R.id.frame_container, new PemegangPolis());
     }else if (usulanAsuransi.isAdded()) {

         fragTrans.replace(R.id.frame_container, new PemegangPolis());
     }else if (detailInvestasi.isAdded()) {

         fragTrans.replace(R.id.frame_container, new PemegangPolis());
     }else if (detail_Agen.isAdded()) {

         fragTrans.replace(R.id.frame_container, new PemegangPolis());
     }else {
         if (dokumenPendukung.isAdded()) {

         fragTrans.replace(R.id.frame_container, new PemegangPolis());
     }
     }
     fragTrans.commit();
     mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(SlidingMenu);
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows...

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new PemegangPolis());
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

transaction.commit();
```